# exists query in slick

Tags: mysql, scala, slick, exists

i have query like bellow

```
  override def isOnList(id: Long, value: String)(implicit ex: ExecutionContext): DBIO[Boolean] = {
    tableQuery.filter(e => e.id === id && e.isActive && e.value === value).exists.result
  }
```

But it returns false when the table does not any rows with id === id. I would like to change this. My modification is

```
  override def isOnList(id: Long, value: String)(implicit ex: ExecutionContext): DBIO[Boolean] = {
    tableQuery.filter(e => e.id === id && e.isActive).result.flatMap {
      case seq if seq.isEmpty => DBIOAction.successful(true)
      case seq => DBIOAction.successful(seq.exists(_.value==value))
    }
  }
```

I am new with slick, so i would like to know that is it good solution or not (i coud not find any information.)?
Oh i forgot, Id is not unique.

Comment: You could just combine the two conditions. `....flatMap(seq => DBIOAction.successful(seq.isEmpty || seq.exists(_.value==value)))`

Answer (score 3):

What is wrong with your first option? It seems to be perfectly valid!

```
def isOnList(id: Long, value: String)(implicit ex: ExecutionContext) : Future[Boolean] = 
    db.run(User.filter(e => e.id === id && e.isActive && e.value === value).exists.result)
```

This method should automatically return true or false depending on the filter condition!

Comment: "But it returns false when the table does not any rows with id === id. I would like to change this". My modification returns true. Not false as the first option. so when the table is empty my first solution returns false and my second solution returns true. Here is the difference.